# Why wont this program wait for x seconds?

Tags: c#

so I am coming from python and I am trying to convert one of my python programs to a c# program. As c# is totally new to me I am already having trouble with a simple thing that in python would look like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

but in c# I cant seem to get it working. Can someone point why it wont wait for 5 seconds before printing "Waited for 5 seconds"?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The code provided will print ‘Hello World’ to the console.
            // Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.

            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Program.wait_for_seconds(5);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited for 5 seconds");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Go to http://aka.ms/dotnet-get-started-console to continue learning how to build a console app! 
        }
        public static async void wait_for_seconds(Double args)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(args));


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `wait_for_seconds` will spawn a task that will complete 5 seconds in the future, but you're not waiting for that task to complete. Basically you're saying "OK, can you call me 1 hour from now? OK, we're done!". Change your `void Main` method to `async Task Main`, then do `await Program.wait_for_seconds(5);`.

Comment: Did you get a warning about the "Program.wait_for_seconds(5);` line by the way?

Comment: After changing the method "void Main" to "async Task Main" I get that I can not await "void"

Comment: Your 'wait_for_seconds' method should be: 'async Task' instead of 'async void'.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not picking up on that, as @PoulBak sais, your `wait_for_seconds` method should be `async Task` instead of `async void`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The nature of async means that it happens at the same time as other things so as @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said your essentially sending a little worker away to go and do something while the main program continues.

If you want your main thread to wait then you could use something like

`Thread.Sleep(5000);`

This will cause your main thread to pause (measured in milliseconds) before continuing to the next line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what async does from the beginning. Thread.Sleep(); should be enough for me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions needed to be called with await keyword. If you don't call your async function with await keyword, it means that you dont care when and how the process is going to finish hence the program does not stop (get blocked) on the function call.

use

```
await Program.wait_for_seconds(5);
```

to see the difference.

PS: please note that you need to change your Main method to

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
```

in order to be able to use await keyword inside main.

Please also note that, you need to enable C# 7.1 features for this change.

the alternative way is calling `Program.wait_for_seconds(5);` method synchronously

```
Program.wait_for_seconds(5).RunSynchronously();
```

or

Program.wait_for_seconds(5).Wait();

But calling async method in synchronous method is not adviced and must not be done.